# Where to find all possible keys for BaseFieldDefinition -> setSettings()

Tags: 8, entities, nodes

I am a noob to Drupal. I am trying to create a module and am currently in the process of creating a content entity and defining its base fields. Can anyone tell me where I can find a list of possible keys for the setSetting method? In other modules I have seen things like:

```
 BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'commerce_store')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
```

How is it that the module creator knew to use target_type and handler??
Any help is much appreciated. I am very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings are specific to each field type, and each type can provide both storage and field settings (storage settings apply to the field as a whole, per type of entity it's used in, and field settings are the per-bundle settings).

For example, the `entity_reference` type, backed by the [`EntityReferenceItem`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21EntityReferenceItem.php/class/EntityReferenceItem/8.6.x) class, provides a `target_type` storage setting, and several field settings (including `handler`).

You can use the API to get the default settings, which equate to the available settings that you're looking for, like this:

```
$field_type_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.field.field_type');
$storage_settings = $field_type_manager->getDefaultStorageSettings('entity_reference');
$field_settings = $field_type_manager->getDefaultFieldSettings('entity_reference');
```

That gets you something like this:

[image]

If you need to inspect the code to find out what's going on, you can find the class responsible for a particular field type with the same service:

```
$class = $field_type_manager->getDefinition('entity_reference')['class'];
```

Comment: As always great info, thanx Clive.